# Android :How to get Battery status without Broadcast Receiver for API level 17 and above?

Tags: android, batterylevel, batterymanager

I want to get Battery status. I searched it on stack and i found the sample code using Broadcast Receiver but problem is that in my code i cannot use Broadcast Receiver.

So is there any way to get battery status without using Broadcast Receiver. It is possible for API 21 and above but i want it for API 17 and above.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent battery=registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

`battery` will contain the last-broadcast `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` `Intent`, and its extras will contain the battery information, using the extra keys documented on `BatteryManager`.

(this code will work inside a method of a `Context` subclass; alternatively, call `registerReceiver()` on some other `Context`)

Comment: Thank you this is what i am looking for